# Open specific item in Settings app from my app in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I have studied several answers and haven't found any that would work for iOS 11.

I want to show the way to switch Background App Refresh on for my user. To do that
I want to open `Settings/General/Background App Refresh` menu from my app.
The following code only opens root menu of the Settings app.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=General&path=BACKGROUND_APP_REFRESH") else { return }

UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Is there any way that would be allowed by Apple to do that?

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible with an URL scheme in iOS 11.

Comment: Apple has never provided any documented method for launching any page of the Settings app except for your own app's page.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the URL [`UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopensettingsurlstring) then you'll be taken your app's settings, which includes background app refresh.

Comment: That is correct, but the goal i want to achieve is to show my user the way to switch on Background App Refresh in case it is switched off

Comment: It will be present in your app’s own settings.

Comment: If the user switched off Background App Refresh in general, there is nothing he can do in my app settings to change that. Background App Refresh will be shown semi-transparent and untouchable

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your app. On my phone, the background app refresh toggle for an app in BAR settings is exactly equivalent to the BAR toggle within the app's settings.

Comment: @BallpointBen There are 2 settings, one is at the app level, one is at the global level. The user can disable Background App Refresh at a global level through out the OS. The question is there a way to open a specific menu in the Settings app that is not for the app.