# How can I get a list of all installed applications in iOS 11+ and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I'm  working on getting the list of all installed apps, [I found a library here](https://github.com/profburke/AppLister).

The problem is that the solution adopted there doesn't support iOS 11+. The list of apps appears only in the simulator, but not on a real device. I tried to work on that by changing private frameworks used with the latest version.

Is there any way to get the list of all installed applications and check whether a specific bundle/app can be opened?

Answer (score 3):

As [the readme of AppLister](https://github.com/profburke/AppLister) says:

> NOTE: As of 5 August 2017 this project is dead. It looks like something's changed in iOS 11 that prevents the key (private) API call from working (allApplications on LSApplicationWorkspace). The method works fine in the simulator, but on a device running iOS 11, it returns zero results.

This method was never encouraged by Apple; [they also removed the undocumented Settings URL schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48771321/3151675) with iOS 11.

If you want to share some content with another application, use a `UIActivityViewController` for that.

Comment: my app will  not be  uploaded  on Appstore